# Get snapshot size on client side - Firestore javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying firestore for some results. But before running forEach loop on docs, i want to know if there are any docs in **collection snapshot**, and `snapshot.exist()` always giving **false** even if there are docs in it.

```
db.collection("users").where("mobile_no", '==', mobileToCheck).get().then(function(querySnapshot){
            if (querySnapshot.exists) {        \\THIS ALWAYS RETURNING FALSE
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                     console.log(doc.data());
                });
                console.log(mobileToCheck + "Exist In DB");
            }else{
                console.log(mobileToCheck + "Do Not Exist In DB");
            }
        });
```

How would i know if there are any results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object doesn't have an `exists` property, that one is only available on [DocumentSnapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

You can either check [`querySnapshot.empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) or [`querySnapshot.size`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size)

Comment: Thanks, that was harder to find. Reason is firebase docs available in multiple places in parts. Thanks.